# Why do two equivalent approaches to selecting numbers that sum to 100 produce different results

Tags: r, sampling, combinatorics

This question is inspired by two seemingly equivalent attempts to solve a question asked yesterday: [In R, how to sample from the output of combn(a,b) if the "a choose b" is too large?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67375/in-r-how-to-sample-from-the-output-of-combna-b-if-the-a-choose-b-is-too-lar)

Essentially the problem is to choose $10$ integers that sum to $100$, where each number must be $\ge 0$.

The approach suggested in the original question is to sample $9$ numbers in the range $1$ to $109$, *without replacement*, and treat these as cut points cutting the range $0$ to $110$. The differences between cutpoints (including $0$ and $110$) give 10 numbers each of which is $\ge 1$. Finally, we subtract  $1$ from each number to get $10$ numbers that are $\ge 0$ and add up to $100$.

An equivalent -- and simpler -- approach, I thought, would be to sample  $9$ numbers in the range $0$ to $100$, *with replacement*. The differences between cutpoints (including $0$ and $100$) directly give 10 numbers that are $\ge 0$ and add up to $100$.

Implementing these approaches in R shows, however, that the approaches are **not** equivalent.

- `y` is the first approach, sampling $9$ numbers from $1\ldots109$ without replacement and adjusting.
- `x` is the second approach, sampling $9$ numbers from $0\ldots100$ with replacement.

From the histograms below, it is apparent that $0$ is sampled a lot more often in the first compared to the second approach.

[image]

Assuming there isn't simply a bug in my second approach, my questions are:

- Why the difference when it seems like intuitively the two approaches should be equivalent?
- Which approach is correct?

R code below for reference

```
set.seed(99)

N=1e5
y <- sapply( 1:N, function(i) {
    diff( c(0, 
            sort(sample(1:109, 9)),
            110) ) - 1
} )

x <- sapply( 1:N, function(i) {
    diff( c(0,
            sort(sample(0:100, 9, replace=TRUE)),
            100) )
} )

p1 <- hist(y, breaks=-0.5:100.5)
p2 <- hist(x, breaks=-0.5:100.5)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(p1, col=rgb(0,0,1))
plot(p2, col=rgb(1,1,0, 0.75))
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541713/how-to-plot-two-histograms-together-in-r
plot(p1, col=rgb(0,0,1), main="x superimposed on y")
plot(p2, col=rgb(1,1,0, 0.75), add=T)
```

Comment: Why don't you work out the exact solution for the simplest case where the two algorithms differ--finding three nonnegative integers summing to $2$? You can easily enumerate all possibilities (six with the first algorithm and nine with the second). The correct result, given by the first algorithm, is that the expected numbers of $0$, $1$, and $2$'s are $9/18$, $6/18$, and $3/18$ respectively, whereas the second algorithm gives $13/27$, $10/27$, and $4/27$ respectively.

Comment: @whuber's point there is so often the right approach - find the *simplest* possible case where the problem occurs, whereupon both the differences and the problems in reasoning are usually more obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have 3 numbers. Without corner cases probability, that you have 0 in the sum is 1/100 in 2nd approach and 2/109 in the 1st approach (numbers are wrong, but I think idea is ok). 
1st sounds more reasonable.

Comment: If the numbers are wrong, how can the idea be correct?